# Unwanted space between last author and followed comma in reference

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I built a .bst file using `makebst` and I want to add a comma before `el al.`. I chose the correct option but it doesn't work. The option in .dbj is as followed

```
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `ET AL':
    %: (def) Comma before `et al'
% etal-xc,%: No comma before `et al'
%--------------------
```

So I modified the generated .bst directly by change

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ ",~et~al." }
```

However, a unexpected space appeared between last author and comma like

```
Mosser B, Michel E, Appourchaux T , et al. A&A, 2009. 506: 33
```

and what I want is

```
Mosser B, Michel E, Appourchaux T, et al. A&A, 2009. 506: 33
```

So, how can I modified the .bst file to fit the request.

Comment: It's easier to answer these questions if one can look at the complete `.bst` file. Can you upload the (unchanged) `.bst` file for us to see? Ideally you would upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. Please don't upload it to a file hoster such as Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: The change to `",~et~al."` can't work because the `.bst` files produced by `makebst` always print an explicit space before `bbl.etal`. You *could* try something like `"\unskip ,~et~al."` (untested) but that feels *very* iffy.

Comment: @moewe I upload the .bst file to my github [https://github.com/MinghaoDu1994/tianwenxuebao-bst/tree/master/twxb_bibstyle]. It seems that `makebst` does not perform perfect, are there any other tools to build a bst file better?

Comment: It seems that the address above can't open,https://github.com/MinghaoDu1994/tianwenxuebao-bst

Answer (score 1):

Your `.bst` file contains three instances of

```
" " * bbl.etal
```

which will print a space followed by "et al."

If you want a comma before the "et al.", replace all three occurences of `" " * bbl.etal` with

```
", " * bbl.etal
```

With the file thus modified (you can get it at https://gist.github.com/moewew/22e8046e747cb39fca28935630ea50c7, there is also a [diff](https://gist.github.com/moewew/22e8046e747cb39fca28935630ea50c7/revisions) so you can see the changes more easily)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby and Mosser, B. and Michel, E. and Appourchaux, T.},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{twxb}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

> [image: Appleby H, Mosser B, Michel E, et al. On the Importance of the Civil Service. 1980]

as desired.

---

Since you have generated your `.bst` file with the option `and-xcom` (which suppresses the comma before "and") it is understandable that you don't get a comma before the "et al." (after all, "et" means "and").

As far as I can see the option `etal-xc` only does something when `and-xcom`, `and-com` and `xand` are not selected.

Comment: I have tried this method and it doesn't work. It indeed comma before the et al, however, before the comma, there exist a space after the last author like what I describe above

Comment: @Minghao It worked for me. See the MWE I posted. You can get the exact file I used at https://gist.github.com/moewew/22e8046e747cb39fca28935630ea50c7

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know why this bst file neither could not abbreviate the journal's name?

Comment: @Minghao As far as I know there is no general feature to abbreviate journal names in `.bst` files. There are some methods to abbreviate a hard-coded list of journals, but that requires special input in the `.bib` file. I suggest you ask a new question about that, since it is unrelated to the "et al." issue.

Comment: It’s fine, once again, thank you!

Comment: @Minghao If the answer helped you, you may want to consider accepting it to mark the question as resolved, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.